# Telepathic female alien crash-lands on earth, fights bug-like aliens

Tags: story-identification, aliens

This has been bugging me for some time now, and I can't find anything on it.

It's a movie I remember watching as a kid with my father and I only remember bits of the movie, just images mostly.

It involves:

- A female telepathic alien that crash lands on earth.
- She finds a local human detective/cop (?) and teams up with him to kill some big bug-like aliens.
- The two protagonists, the female alien and the cop, are walking up some stairs after a meeting. She's in front and as she climbs the stairs he looks at her butt. She immediately turns around and says something to the effect of "that's gross".

I hope this is enough for someone to help me identify the movie. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 12):

I suggest [*Something is Out There*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Something_Is_Out_There).

This 1988 (right time frame?) mini-series spawned a very brief TV series, so finding that specific scene would be tough, but here is a link to the intro:

It has:

1. Bug-like aliens
2. Telepathic female alien
3. Said female alien is played by Maryam D'abo, so a male checking out her posterior is completely plausible.

Comment: That's it! I had forgotten it was a tv series, but the intro has the scene I remembered! Good thin I posted, I was wrecking my brain trying to think of the name. Now I can go back and watch it again, thank you!

Comment: @Edward: It would be greatly appreciated if you can click the green check mark to indicate that this is indeed the correct answer. It helps our metrics and later querents.